# LWC- Construct url of a page based on clicked value

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I have a community Page that contains a table with values.
I want that when I click a line of the table (with for example : id=**XXXXX**). I want to access another existing page and construct the **url** of this page with the clicked id.

Page Url: "/Test/s/details"

New Url :"/Test/s/details?id=**XXXXX**"

Comment: Are you actually using LWC here? Sometimes people apply tags incorrectly, especially when new here. So I just want to clarify.

Comment: Yes I'm using LWC.

Answer (score 1):

So there will be two ways to do this.

1. Make your table rows (records) their own component.

This way, you can pass the record into the child component. From here, you can simply use `window.href`, or the [LWC navigation mix-in](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation) if you want to dynamically get community page urls too. If you use the navigation mix in, you can use the generateURL function to get the base URL for the page and then append the url parameters (your Id) to that string. Then just use an Anchor tag.

2. Otherwise, on whatever you want to be clickable, add the id as a data-attribute and handle the click in Javascript.

`<a href="" data-id={record.Id} onclick={handleClick}>{record.Name}</a>`

```
handleClick(evt){
  var id = evt.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  if (id){
    window.location = '/Test/s/details?id=' + id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the community, you can definitely use NavigationMixin to satisfy the requirements, but if one is implementing a standalone application, take a look at lwc-router, which is built keeping in mind these types of use - cases

You might also need bookmarking features, page state and URL parameters which can also be tackled using lwc-router, as it implements History API

https://github.com/prashantk0001/lwc-router

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way is to set the URLs as properties of the objects in your table data array.  For example, if you have a wired Apex method that returns a list of SObjects, and you want to use the `Id` value on those objects in your URL, you can use a JS `Array.map()` function to add url props to the objects on arrival:

```js
@track data = [];

@wire(getTableData, { recordId: "$recordId" })
loadData({ data, error }) {
    if (data && data.length) {
        this.data = data.map(row => {
            return {
                ...row,
                url: "/Test/s/details?id=" + row.Id
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your template, you can use the `url` directly:

```html
<table>
    <tr for:each={data} for:item="row">
        <td>
            <a href={row.url}>{row.Name}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```